# install numpy and matplotlib to locally installed python2.7 in linux

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I installed python2.7 linux locally through

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME
make
make install
```

then how can I install modules numpy & matplotlib to it?

The system of server is Fedora x86_64. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Install distribute:

```
 curl -O http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py
 ~/bin/python distribute_setup.py
```

Install pip (not necessary, but helpful):

```
 ~/bin/easy_install pip
```

Install packages:

```
 ~/bin/pip install numpy
 ~/bin/pip install matplotlib
```